# Quadratic Approximation for Log-Likelihood Ratio Processes, Why and How

Tags: likelihood-ratio, quadratic-form

I'm trying to understand why the quadratic equation can approximate the log likelihood ratio.[image]

Is this approximated using Taylor's series or normal distribution equation or anything else?

Comment: Please describe the situation you are referring to, and define your variables.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The main goal here to derive a supported range (similar to the 95% CI) for the likelihood ratio. In book 'Essential Medical statistics' Chapter 28, it was mentioned that the log of the likelihood ratio (LR) is used instead of the likelihood itself, because the log(LR) can be approximated by a quadratic equation (the one shown above), for easier calculation. It is also said that this equation is chosen so as to meet the curve of and to have the same curvature as the log(LR) at the MLE. I cannot figure out why is this, and how was this equation derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The idea is to expand the log-likelihood function using Taylor series. The Taylor series of a function $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is:

$$
  f(x) = f(x_0) + \frac{f^{(1)}(x_0)}{1!}(x-x_0) + \frac{f^{(2)}(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + \cdots
$$

In your case, $f(x) = log(LR)$. And you are expanding it not at a random point, but specifically around the maximum, which means you require $f^{(1)}(x_0) = 0$. So there are only the constant term, the quadratic term, and higher order terms. For small $(x-x_0)$, you may ignore the higher order terms and the $log(LR)$ is approximated with a quadratic function. A quadratic log-likelihood also corresponds to a normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying ! I think the X(0) here should be MLE, but I cannot work out the process to arrive at the formula above, and where the 1/S^2 (standard error) comes from.

Comment: Using Taylors expansion I get $ -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{(MLE-\theta)^2}{\theta^2})$.